# Java Executor Not Performing Sequentially

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, executor

I apologize in advance if this is a basic question, but I'm new to the material.  I've got a piece of software that is kicked off by user's submitting jobs through a website.  Because the software is itself designed to capitalize on parallel processing, all I want to do is queue up these jobs so they can kick off one after the other.  To do this, I've tried to capitalize on the Executor framework built into Java.  The code I've developed is:

```
public JobManager()
{
    mcpExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
}

public Future<MatlabProcessResults> startProcess(inputs)
{
    MyProcess myProcess = new MyProcess(inputs);
    Future<MyProcessResults> future = mcpExecutor.submit(myProcess);

    Long newKey = System.currentTimeMillis();
    futures.putIfAbsent(newKey, future);
}
```

Where startProcess is run every time the "submit" button is pressed.  Now, the description of the newSingleThreadExecutor reads:

> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time. Unlike the otherwise equivalent newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads.

This led me to think that it would take multiple tasks, queue them, and only run one instance of the software at a time.  As you might suspect, I'm writing because it doesn't do that.  It is starting as many tasks as I submit in parallel (I know, the opposite problem of what most people probably want to do).  Any help on this issue is much appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Comment: are you passing your jobs to the same executor instance?

Comment: `newSingleThreadExecutor()` does not start threads in parallel, your testing method is flawed. Its as simple as that. You can verify the sequentialisation with `System.out` and a `volatile int` - each output of this `volatile int` will be ordered, the value will increase sequentially. So as long as your `ExecutorService` is `static` your problem description is impossible. My guess is : you keep instantiating `JobManager` hence create new `ExecutorService`s in each thread .... its a beginners mistake.

Comment: @pnaermao show relevant parts of your MyProcess class; also, are you sure requests go to the same JobRequest instance? it is not a singleton and your executor is not static